# Features that doesn't run on simulator (iOS development)

Tags: ios

I know that things like push notifications or camera doesn't run on simulator. There are other tasks that only with a real device can be done. But I would like to know exactly what all of these tasks are needed to be executed on the device, and not on simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for example camera .it does not  present in simulator & GPS also same

Comment: @SudheerKolasani, reading the question brings happiness and joy. Try it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really lot of differencies between  `iOS` simulator/device such as `OpenG ES` (rendering), `API` (some features/`frameworks` are not supported by `simulator`), `accessibility` and so on, but if you are asking about hardware so here the list:

**Hardware Differences**

Though most of the functionality of devices can be simulated in Simulator, some hardware features must be tested directly on a device.

The hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2 are:

- Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
- Audio and video input (camera and microphone) are unsupported.
- Proximity sensor
- Barometer
- Ambient light sensor

---

More here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html

Comment: That was I was looking for!

Comment: Nice answer, you can also add 3D-Touch which cannot be simulated for now.